# Show that the alternating group $A_9$ has no subgroups of index 8?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So far, I believe it's a proof by contradiction. Suppose that $H \leq A_9$ with $[A_9 : H] = 8$.. $|H| = |A_9|*8$(which is a large number)? then would this involve the 3-cycles? Quite stumped.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is  $|H|*8 = |A_9|$, and you have typed $A_4$ instead of $A_8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $A_9$ has a subgroup $H$ of index 8. Then $A_9$ acts by left-multiplication on the set $A_9/H$ of left-cosets of $H$, and this induces a homomorphism $A_9 \to \text{Sym}(A_9/H) \cong S_8$. Now use the fact that  $A_9$ is simple.